# Shopify: Take 4 - Pay 3 not working anymore with PayPal Checkout

Tags: paypal, shopify, paypal-sandbox, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am running a Take 4 - Pay 3 Offer on my Shopify Store. For MONTHS, and today i figured out, that PayPal does not consider the Discount when checking out with PayPal, neither PayPal Express Checkout (On Checkout Page) nor normal PayPal after putting in address details.

1 Product Costs 9,95

- Take 4 , Pay 3 - its 39,80 (4) - 9,95(1 free) = 29,85€

But instead of letting the customer pay 29,85 it asks them to pay 39,80.

Comment: Seems you should contact Shopify for support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.